# 0xc0000225 error after P2V with VMWare Converter

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, bsod, physical-to-virtual

I'm having an error with a P2V conversion of a Server 2008 R2 machine with VMWare Converter. The machine is going from an HP server to a Dell 2950.

The machine fails to boot and spits out a 0xc0000225 error. I have read into this error quite extensively and all the recommendations I have found do not seem to work. During the conversion I've used the LSI Logic SAS controller - I've also re-done the conversion to use LSI Logic Parallel with similar results.

I have tried the following

- Run startrep.exe (fails to repair any issues)
- Adjusted the Start properties of the registry entries ControlSet001 –> Services –> LSI_SAS as outlined [HERE](http://www.azmer.my/p2v-windows-server-2008-blue-screen-0x0000007b/)
- Retried the conversion with the LSI Logicl Parallel disk controller rather than the LSI Logic SAS controller
- Removed all other hard drives from the VM except the boot drive to ensure the machine was attempting to boot from proper hard drive

Can anyone shed a bit of light as to what's going on? I've used this host machine for several Hyper V conversions that were sitting on the same box without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this issue. I realized that the BSOD message was stating that there was an issue with ADDS (this was a domain controller) - I had assumed the BSOD stop message would be the same as the boot error message (listed in the OP), however I was wrong. I attempted to boot into DSRM and resolve the issue, however was unsuccessful. The original administrator had moved the AD database to the D: drive and the only drive that was mounting in DSRM was the C:.

I went to the original physical machine and moved the database back to C:\Windows\NTDS using ntdsutil and performed the conversion again and the machine booted without a BSOD.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, but was able to fix it by booting server to safe mode, F8.  Once booted, I let all the device drivers install (since P-to-V process introduces new hardware). While this was on-going, I used DISKMGMT.MSC to mount the D: and E: drives that my original Physical server had.  Before I was able to do this, I had to change the drive letter of the CDROM within this tool; I chose R: drive (instead of D:).

Once the drives mounted to their original letters and device drivers were loaded, I rebooted and all was well.